# How to set/add overall chart padding to Circos/Chord in d3 graph?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, circos

How to add chart overll padding for circos/chord chart?

I have similar kind of chord chart with same attributes please see given link [https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/chord_basic.html].

Actually I want to set overall chart padding(top,right,bottom and left side), without modify in its height and width. I have tried with some attributes and style in editor mode but it does not work.

Can you please suggest solution how to set overall padding for circos/chord chart with example?

Thanks

Comment: in the case of the basic chord diagram where you have `<svg width="440" height="440">` you can add a viewBox attribute like so: if the desired padding is of 20 user units use <svg width="440" height="440"  viewBox="-20 -20 480 480"> where 480 = 440 + 2*20

Comment: Please post the code and what you have tried and where you are struck specifically , please read how to post questions in stack overflow

Comment: Hi enxaeta,
Thanks for the reply. As sugesstion viewbox is not working in svg.

// create the svg area
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 440)
    .attr("height", 440)
    .attr("viewbox", "20,20,480,480")

please correct me if am using wrong syntax. My circos/chord chart is plotting similar way for more details please check below provided.

link: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/chord_basic.html.

Comment: Hi @Gotham J.M
Thanks for reply.

I have similar kind of example [link](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/chord_basic.html) on thier editir tried to add padding attribute on svg element but it doesnt work.

Only I have seen padding between entities (black arc) i.e padAngle, and if you want to provide padding for overall chart area then how to apply for this D3 chart. Please provide any solution. 

For more deatils i have provide circos chart link above. Please check once.

Comment: Hi Team, 
Please provide the solution for above query it will help us.

Thanks